# Adding a Select List (Text) field to an entity bundle programmatically

Tags: entities

I've been searching for hours, but can't seem to find a solution to this. Now, I'm able to create a plain old text field as such as this:

In moduleA.install:

```
if (!field_info_field('field_myfield')) {
  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_myfield',
    'type' => 'text',
  );
  field_create_field($field);
}
```

Then, in moduleB.install, I add that field to a specific taxonomy bundle:

```
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => 'field_myfield',
  'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
  'label' => 'MyField',
  'bundle' => 'new_terms',
  'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'text',
  ),
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

What I would like is the field it creates to be a select list, instead of just a text field. I've been looking around, trying to figure it out (using "list-select" in place of type), but any time I've deviated from what's above, I get an error on field_create_instance when installing moduleB. I realize it's probably (hopefully) something as simple as knowing the proper widget name, but I either can't seem to find it, or am searching for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field type would be `list_text` (as defined in [`list_field_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_field_info/7), and the widget type is `options_select`, as defined in [`options_field_widget_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!options!options.module/function/options_field_widget_info/7).

Kind of tricky to track down, but this little snippet should help in future:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$field_name = 'field_name';
$bundle_name = 'article';

$info_config = field_info_field($field_name);
$info_instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
unset($info_config['id']);
unset($info_instance['id'], $info_instance['field_id']);
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/utility.inc';
$output = "field_create_field(" . drupal_var_export($info_config) . ");\n";
$output .= "field_create_instance(" . drupal_var_export($info_instance) . ");";
drupal_set_message("<textarea rows=30 style=\"width: 100%;\">". $output .'</textarea>');
```

It'll get you a complete field and instance definition of an existing field, ready to use in code.

Comment: Would I still use "text" or "list-text" as the type when creating the field?

Comment: Sorry, I completely mis-understood what you were asking. I've updated the answer

Comment: Oh! Actually, the way you had it before was fine; I figured out the other bit after some testing. Thank you!